# How to deep link login to a React SPA

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot

I'm currently developing a React SPA with a Spring Boot backend API.
For one use case i need to create a dynamic link which contains login credentials for a one-time-User. With this link a user needs to be able to login to the SPA and use it further from outside the application.

This is the first time I'm working with a SPA.
What is the best way to achieve this goal?

I would really appreciate some ideas.

best regards

Comment: I would say it's more like back-end issue. React is just for UI

Comment: I would suggest to create separate route for that, like `/login/:token` and if token is exists and valid - run log in function.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a Router (like [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)). These cause different components to be rendered in React depending on the current URL, and from there different code can be run (likely from event handlers or `useEffect` if you're using function components).